# Entity Framework 4.0 . Entity Creation

Tags: entity-framework-4

We have two entities with identical columns but the entity name is different. Can i create 2 entity using the first entity instance ?

We tried doing .AddObject("Entity2 name",entityOneinstance) but it is failing.

Please suggest whether this is possible or any other approach.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since the types of entities are different, your add operation will fall for sure.

You will need a mapper or (explicit/implicit) conversion operator between your entity types I think.

To make it clear, for the conversation solution, suppose you have `Entity1` and `Entity2` and both have properties, `Property`, `Property_1`, `Property_2` and `Property_3`. I assume that you have default code generation strategy (not POCO or sth). Then you can add partial Entity2 and Entity1 classes with implicit conversion operatior, for example:

```
public partial class Entity2
{
    public static implicit operator Entity2(Entity1 entity1)
    {
        return new Entity2()
        {
            Property = entity1.Property,
            Property_1 = entity1.Property_1,
            Property_2 = entity1.Property_2,
            Property_3 = entity1.Property_3
        };
    }
}
```

So you can now do:

```
using (var provider = new Model1Container12())
{
    Entity1 entity1 = new Entity1();
    provider.AddObject(provider.Entity2Set.Name, entity1);
    // or
    provider.AddToEntity2Set(entity1);
}
```

The conversion will be made implicitly as you define in the conversion operator definition.

I don't know if Entity Framework itself has a solution for this situation but conversion seems like a solution for me. Or you can also use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) kind of thing. I don't have detailed information on that.

Comment: Mean that i have to create separate entity instances for each ? either of entity can't be reused to add another entity into the database table ? Kindly clarify.

Comment: I guess you need to create an instance of type which you want to add to your entity context. I have updated my answer. Hope to be helpful. Please notify if the answer is not clear, or I misunderstand the situation.

Answer (score 0):

In EF4, ObjectSet was introduced, which is kinda nifty..

My approach would be using repository pattern...

First create an abstract base class..

```
    public abstract class BaseRepository<T> where T : class
{
    #region Members

    protected IObjectSet<T> _objectSet;

    #endregion

    #region Ctor

    public BaseRepository(ObjectContext context)
    {
        _objectSet = context.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        _objectSet.AddObject(entity);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _objectSet;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then create a derived class for each tabel you need to access..

An example (interface and implemtation):
Producer is the tables POCO object.

Interface:

```
    public interface IProducerRepository
{
    Producer GetById(int id);
    void Add(Producer entity);
    IEnumerable<Producer> GetAll();
}
```

Implementation:

```
    public class ProducerRepository : BaseRepository<Producer>, IProducerRepository
{
    #region Ctor

    public ProducerRepository(ObjectContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public Producer GetById(int id)
    {
        return _objectSet.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
    }


    #endregion
}
```

Hope this helps.. :-)